# Does a restriction to $x$ set when finding $y'$ from solving a second order differential equation affect the domain of the solution? (pursuit curves)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving a problem regarding pursuit curves. The initial differential equation is the following:
\begin{equation}
xy'' = \sigma \sqrt{1+(y')^2}
\end{equation}

I used the substitution $v=y'$, thus obtaining:
\begin{equation}
xv' = \sigma \sqrt{1+v^2}
\end{equation}

From where:
\begin{equation}
\ln{\left|v + \sqrt{1+v^2}\right|} = \sigma \ln{|x|} + c
\end{equation}

My question arises here. Solving this equation, a restriction is set to the value of x: $x\neq 0$. But is this restriction only valid when talking about the function $v(x)=y'(x)$? That is, can $x=0$ in the final function $y(x)$? Or does this restriction propagate and affect the final solution $y(x)$?

My concern is mainly due to the fact that I have to evaluate the solution at $x=0$ and find what its corresponding value of $y$ is.

The solution $y(x)$ is the following:

\begin{equation}
y(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left( c_1 \frac{x^{\sigma +1}}{\sigma +1} - \frac{x^{1-\sigma}}{c_1(1-\sigma)}\right) + c_2
\end{equation}
$\sigma$ is a value that for the purposes of the problem is less than 1. This function doesn't have a problem if $x= 0$, but in the process of finding it, such restriction is set. I'm not entirely sure if it'd be valid to evaluate the solution at $x=0$, or if the restriction only applies to its derivative, which is:
\begin{equation}
y'(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left( c_1 x^{\sigma} - \frac{1}{c_1 x^{\sigma}}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Since you were talking about pursuit curves, I assume you were solving a physics problem. From a physics point of view it does not matter. Even the $x\neq 0$ condition is not required for the $v$ function. The reason we say $x\neq 0$ is because the domain of log is $(0,\infty)$, which is because at $0$ log gives a $-\infty$ value which is not plottable. But from a physics pov it just means that as $x$ becomes very close to $0$, the value of $v$ tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: The problem is that of a dog chasing a rabbit. The rabbit runs up the y-axis and the dog chases the rabbit always pointing directly to it starting at some position $x_0$. I'm asked to find the point $y$ at which the dog catches the rabbit, i.e $y(0)$. For the derivative to approach -$\infty$ when x -> 0 makes sense if you look at the graph., since the slope of the line that joins the two gets negatively steeper and steeper. However, I'm still troubled by the restriction that arises of $x \neq 0$. I guess the nature of it could be explained by analyzing the actual behavior of the situation.

Comment: Note that you can avoid the implicit stage if you set $y'=\sinh(u)$, as $xu'=σ$ follows and is easily solvable.

Comment: Using $y' = \sinh{(u)}$ and solving $xu' = \sigma$ would still throw the restriction $x \neq 0$, wouldn't it? Though I reckon that substitution to be more... elegant.